# How to load a complex datastructure like struct ,map in HIVE table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I  am trying insert below data in to an hive table:

John Doe^A100000.0^AMary Smith^BTodd Jones^AFederal Taxes^C.2^BState
Taxes^C.05^BInsurance^C.1^A1 Michigan Ave.^BChicago^BIL^B60600

Mary Smith^A80000.0^ABill King^AFederal Taxes^C.2^BState Taxes^C.
05^BInsurance^C.1^A100 Ontario St.^BChicago^BIL^B60601

Todd Jones^A70000.0^AFederal Taxes^C.15^BState Taxes^C.03^BInsurance^C.
1^A200 Chicago Ave.^BOak Park^BIL^B60700

Bill King^A60000.0^AFederal Taxes^C.15^BState Taxes^C.03^BInsurance^C.
1^A300 Obscure Dr.^BObscuria^BIL^B60100

**This is the query I am using:**

CREATE TABLE employees (

name STRING,

salary FLOAT,

subordinates ARRAY,

deductions MAP,

address STRUCT
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED

FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'

COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\002'

MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\003'

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

STORED AS TEXTFILE

LOAD LOCAL INPATH '/home/cloudera/a.txt';

BUT the all the detail stored in one column.Can anybody please explain the reason.

John Doe^A100000.0^AMary Smith^BTodd Jones^AFederal Taxes^C.2^BState    NULL    null    null    null
Taxes^C.05^BInsurance^C.1^A1 Michigan Ave.^BChicago^BIL^B60600    NULL    null    null    null
Mary Smith^A80000.0^ABill King^AFederal Taxes^C.2^BState Taxes^C.    NULL    null    null    null
05^BInsurance^C.1^A100 Ontario St.^BChicago^BIL^B60601    NULL    null    null    null
Todd Jones^A70000.0^AFederal Taxes^C.15^BState Taxes^C.03^BInsurance^C.    NULL    null    null    null
1^A200 Chicago Ave.^BOak Park^BIL^B60700    NULL    null    null    null
Bill King^A60000.0^AFederal Taxes^C.15^BState Taxes^C.03^BInsurance^C.    NULL    null    null    null
1^A300 Obscure Dr.^BObscuria^BIL^B60100    NULL    null    null    null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be the issue with the input data file, have you created this file manually , you need to insert the delimited characters inside the file correctly  , i would suggest  you can download the sample text file from the book website (i assume you are referring programming hive book) and then give a try . the input file is available there and i am able to load that so...

Answer (score 0):

meet the same problem.

solved by when create your table, change default ROW FORMAT DELIMITED, **'\001' -> ','  '\002' -> ';'  '\003' -> ':'**

then you can prepare your text file using the above chars to split.